# how can I see what I get through request in an update method?

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I am doing an update method through a form and I want to check what I am getting through request in my back using laravel, but using dd or ddd I get something unreadable, is there anything similar to console.log in javascript so I can see in a normal way what is being sent???

Comment: Have you tried to return the values using `return $data;` ?

Comment: Is it "something unreadable" because you `dd()` the whole request object? Have you tried the "Network" tab in your Browser's DevTools? Have you tried `$request->all()`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Can you please post your update() code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to save the value using a session from the Controller: `session(['result' => $result]);`, show it on your blade view using `session('result');`.

Answer (score 1):

`dd($request->all())` is what you need to do when you want to dump form data from request.

If you do `dd($request)`, we will get every data from the request, basically tons of information.